# relation between input and output torques for a geared machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque, rotational-kinematics

what is the torque in both ends of this gear set ?
thanks!

Multiple speed gear paradox box
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIMDtkm_ENQ
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: What is the paradox? You appear to be asking us to solve a puzzle for you, which is *off topic*, particularly as you have not shown any effort to solve the problem yourself. If there is something you do not understand you are welcome to ask about that.

Comment: Thanks. I dont understand what is the relation between input(red)/ output(green) torques in this device ? Which is greater? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The device has no energy sources inside which might magnify what is input, so the maximum amount of work you can get out of it is the same as the work you put in. This is simply a statement of the **Conservation of Energy** : you cannot get out more than you put in.

Work done by a rotating shaft is the torque on the shaft times the angle through which it turns. Assuming no energy losses due to friction : $$\text{work in = work out}$$ $$\text{input torque x input angle = output torque x output angle}$$

The caption to the video tells you the relation between input and output angles, so that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please consider planetary gear set torque equations and see the video.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What gear set torque equations? Your question asked for the relation between input and output torques, which is what I showed in my answer. I watched the video.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicyclic_gearing   Torque ratios of standard epicyclic gearing

Comment: How does this relate to your question? The video caption states what the **gear ratio** is for this device (GR=output angle/input angle). You asked about **torques** not gear ratio.